# Laravel get the data and display it in the blade html failed

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get data from the database and simply display it in the view

```
public function index()
{
    $messages = ProjectInterestedMessages::get();

    return view('dashboard/projects-interests', compact($messages));
}
```

The view

```
@foreach ($messages as $message)
    <h1>{{ $message->first_name }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

But I am getting this error

```
compact(): Argument #1 must be string or array of strings, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP method `compact()` is a little tricky with its syntax.  I make this same mistake all the time.

Change:

```
return view('dashboard/projects-interests', compact($messages));
```

to:

```
return view('dashboard/projects-interests', compact('messages'));
```

`compact()` looks for a string representation of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could write this.

using compact where you pass strings representing the variable

```
public function index()
{
    $messages = ProjectInterestedMessages::get();

    return view('dashboard/projects-interests', compact('messages'));
}
```

using ->with

```
public function index()
{
    $messages = ProjectInterestedMessages::get();

    return view('dashboard/projects-interests')->with(['messages' => $messages]);
}
```

With using laravel magic

```
public function index()
{
    $messages = ProjectInterestedMessages::get();

    return view('dashboard/projects-interests')->withMessages($messages);
}
```

Personally, I prefer this form as it avoids pointless variables

```
public function index()
{
    return view('dashboard/projects-interests')
        ->withMessages(ProjectInterestedMessages::get());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $

return view('dashboard/projects-interests', compact('messages'));